# In flutter, how to give ratio to video player like it's Boxfit.cover

Tags: flutter

I'm making a widget that shows the video and I want to make that widget's ratio can be changed to 1/1, 3/4 or 4/3 if the user click the button.

I used FittedBox widget and fit is Boxfit.cover, but it occurs the error that

TextureBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: RenderFittedBox#a3383 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderFittedBox#a3383 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
The relevant error-causing widget was
VideoPlayer

Therefore I used ClipRRect and it changes the ratio, but it's not BoxFit.cover.

This is the code how I did

```
AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: controller.ratio.value == 0
                                    ? 1 / 1
                                    : controller.ratio.value == 1
                                        ? 4 / 3
                                        : 3 / 4,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                    child: VideoPlayer(videoController!)),
                              )
```

How to make the video fitted in aspectratio. Do I need to use other video player package?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get a video to cover a certain area w/o distorting its original aspect ratio and I used the following code.  Maybe this can be a starting point for what you need.

Try something like the following:

```
class VideoBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  const VideoBackground({Key? key, required this.videoPlayerController, this.fit = BoxFit.contain}) : super(key: key);
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  final BoxFit fit;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final aspectRatio = videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio;
    print('aspectRatio = $aspectRatio');
    const videoHeight = 100.0;
    final videoWidth = videoHeight * aspectRatio;
    return FittedBox(
      fit: fit,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
          ? SizedBox(
              height: videoHeight,
              width: videoWidth,
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController),
              ),
            )
          : Container(color: Colors.transparent, height: 1, width: 1),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and change Boxfit.contain to Boxfit.cover, but it didn't work. The video is keep shrink. However, thanks for your help